# PHP + Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to delete a row in mysql database by Javascript confirmation box.

```
<?php
$select_items= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items"); 
$row_select_items= mysql_fetch_array($select_items)
extract($row_select_items);

$db_item_id=$row_select_items['db_item_id'];
echo "<a href=\"index.php?type=delete&value=$db_item_id\">Delete</a>";
?>
```

As soon as user click on "Delete" link, I want to get a javascript confirm box to confirm the deletion. If it yes delete the row with certain id, if it no just close the pop up box.

Comment: Do you need PHP or JS code for that?

Comment: He needs both. And probably he needs to understand that Javascript runs on the client (browser) whereas PHP runs on the server. So he needs a Javascript that when confirmed sends a request to the server where this PHP delete code is executed.

Answer (score 2):

In the link you can add:

```
"<a href=\"index.php?type=delete&value=$db_item_id\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\">Delete</a>";
```

Comment: I'd go with that answer, too. Please make sure that you check on the backend whether the user is allowed to delete that item or people could just call all id's and delete all items.